# How to create instance of contract that deployed by another contract?

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Lets say i've deployed an contract using a function in another contract:

```
function createCollection(
    uint256 _price, uint256 _maxSupply, string memory _name, string memory _symbol, address _requsetFrom, string memory _uri, bytes32 salt
    ) external payable returns(address)  {
        if (msg.value < s_createFee) {
            revert CollectionCreator__InsufficientAmount();
        }
        // CollectionV2 newNft = new CollectionV2(_name,_symbol,_price,_maxSupply,_requsetFrom, _uri);
        CollectionV2 newNft = (new CollectionV2){salt: salt}(_name,_symbol,_price,_maxSupply,_requsetFrom, _uri);
        address _contractAddress = address(newNft);
        ownerToCollection[_requsetFrom].push(_contractAddress);
    emit NewCollection(_requsetFrom, _contractAddress);
    return(_contractAddress);
}
```

And this is my backend code:

```
  const Collection = await ERC721Creator.createCollection(1,100,'alireza','arz',deployer.address,"chert")
  const tx = await Collection.wait(1)
  const CollectionV2 = tx.events[0].args[1]
```

The question is that, how i can create an instance for this contract to interact with?
Because i can't create instance by `getContract()` like another contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getContractAt()` like this:

```
const Collection = await ERC721Creator.createCollection(1,100,'alireza','arz',deployer.address,"chert")
const tx = await Collection.wait(1)
const CollectionV2Address = tx.events[0].args[1]
const CollectionV2 = await ethers.getContractAt("CollectionV2", CollectionV2Address)
```

Make sure that "CollectionV2" is the right artifact name, so `getContractAt()` has the correct ABI. If `CollectionV2` uses a different artifact name, use it instead in the `getContractAt()` call.

Comment: Thank you, it works...